# Put a Array in another Array by comparing their values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, explode

I got two arrays. Array A with Soccer-Player positions and array B with Soccer-Players.
Every Player got a name and a position.

Now I wanted to split array B in the different postions of array A and re-order it in one array sorted like the positions in array A.

The arrays look like this:

**Array A**
    Array ( tor, 
            abwehr, 
            mittelfeld, 
            sturm )

**Array B**
    Array ( Array ( Rocky, Sturm ), 
            Array ( Kevin, Abwehr ) )

My result array should look like this:

```
Array ( tor, 
        abwehr(Array ( Kevin, Abwehr )), 
        mittelfeld, 
        sturm(Array ( Rocky, Sturm )) )
```

My code till now:

```
$positionen = array("tor", "abwehr", "mittelfeld", "sturm");
foreach($positionen as $position) {

$team = $extern_source->api();  
foreach($team['data'] as $team) {


//need to explode this to filter relevant infos
$team_info = explode("\n",$team['info']);

$sp_name=$team_info[1];
$sp_posi=$team_info[4];
//put together the single infos in a new array
...
```

I really hope you understand my problem. 
It put knots in my brain. so complicated :D

Thank you very much!
Best regards from Germany.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arrayB as $player){
 $position[$player[1]][] = $player[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First prepare the final array before the first `foreach`:

```
$data = array_fill_keys($positionen, array());
```

Then after feching the *name* and the *position*, do this:

```
$data[$sp_posi][] = $sp_name;
```

*Note: `array_fill_keys` requires PHP 5.2 or higher*